# No Option for Unmanaged Package

Tags: package

I must say that the documentation and information for Packaging is quite confusing.

That being said, I'm trying to become as well versed in Packaging so I'll be ready for a release in the near future.

Here is the issue, in screen one, I have permission to create Managed and Unmanaged Packaged

[image: Screen 1]

In Screen 2, which follows, there are only options for Managed Beta and Release.
I believe this is a DE environment.

[image: Screen 2]

Thank you.

Comment: The images are reversed. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem, I've fixed the order for you now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have defined a namespace (as in 'trmn' in your case) in a DE org, you can only have one managed package defined in it, though you can have further unmanaged packages if you wish. A package can only be of one type, [managed or unmanaged](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sharing_apps.htm&language=en_US), not both at once. The docs do not really state why you would want to have multiple packages in a DE org (mutiple unmanaged or one managed and multiple unmanaged), but you can.

What your seeing in your second screenshot is the options shown when you attempt to 'upload' your managed package (the one associated with the 'trmn' namespace). Hence you only see references to the term 'Managed'. If you create another package (which will have to be an unmanaged one), and attempt to upload this you will see a screen like this when clicking the Upload button.

[image]

The [ISV Force guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/index.htm) is a great reference to managed packages and the process,

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. The part I was missing is that you cannot create more than one Managed Package in one org.

Comment: Your most welcome! :-)

Comment: hi @AndrewFawcett, what would be a valid scenario for having both an unmanaged and managed package in the same org?

Comment: From my perspective, as an ISV, we don't develop in the packaging org, its really just used as a means to release. So I'm struggling to think of why you would. I have in the past in some adhoc cases, just created one to get some components copied out of the org and into another, then deleted the unmanaged package afterwards. That can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can create more than one package in your org, but only one can be managed. The managed package can never be uploaded as "unmanaged", but you can create a new package and upload that one as unmanaged.